# cant access my homepage using codeigniter framework

Tags: codeigniter

I just uploaded my site and it cant enter my home page it keeps saying that the homepage is not found. my routes are set to home.php and in my home.php file the class Home extends CI_Controller can anyone help i need answers ASAP. Thanks.

this is my routes.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = "home";
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

Comment: More information is needed here... Please post your `routes.php`.

Comment: Did you change your base_url var in config.php? Also, do you have the index.php file in your project root dir?

Comment: no i didnt change my base_url and i do have the index.php

Comment: Have you added anything to your .htaccess file? Any modifications?

Comment: no i didnt modify my htaccess

Answer (score 0):

**Possible problems:**

**1.** If it's showing a general 404 error (not the CodeIgniter page not found error), I would make sure that you actually have a linked view. If CI can't load a view from a controller, it will throw a 404.

**2.** Your server might not be parsing the URI correctly. I've personally had the most luck with setting the `uri_protocol` in config.php to `'PATH_INFO'`

$config['uri_protocol'] = 'PATH_INFO';

**3.** The CI documentation is a great read, especially the troubleshooting section:

- http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/installation/index.html
- http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/installation/troubleshooting.html
- http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/overview/getting_started.html

Answer (score 0):

1. load url_helper in autoload.php (application/config/autoload.php)

   `$autoload['helper'] = array('url');`
2. Define base_url() in config.php (application/config/config.php)

   `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/your_codeigniter_directory/';`
3. Set default controller in routes.php (application/config/route.php)

   `$route['default_controller'] = 'controllername';`
4. place your homepage.php in views (application/views)
5. place your controller in controllers directory (application/controllers)
6. code inside controller

   `class Controllername extends CI_Controller {
         public function index()
   {
       $this->load->view('view_name');
   }
   }`
7. now open url in your browser http://localhost/your_codeigniter_directory/